# In Spring security the authenticationmanager's with usernamequery cannot search with username and password

Tags: spring-boot

builder.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource())
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, password, enabled from users where username=? and password=?")

Throws an error

"PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [select username, password, enabled from users where username=? and password=?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 2",

Comment: No it cannot and will not. Password check is done in memory not in the query. It has one parameter and that is the username.

Comment: Ok......but is there any method that I can check it with username and password. Or do I need to do it manually by taking username and password from headers.

Comment: Spring Security does the checking for you... Why would you need to do it yourself. Looks like you are working around Spring Security instead of using it.

Comment: I am learning and implementing spring security, so while doing basic authentication it is getting verified by username only and not by username and password. If I am giving incorrect password then it shows success when username is correct, when username it incorrect it throws error.

Comment: Why should you implement anything? You should only need to configure things. Password check is done by spring security, if you are overriding classes and don't do this check (not sure why you would need to override anything) then well yes things break.